# Got an Access DB with absolute paths that I can't modify. Migrating to new fileshare PC. Hostname is now wrong

Tags: windows, microsoft-access, migration, hostname

I'd put this on Stackoverflow but it's a "How to fix an MS Access related prob using anything except MS Access".

I'm fine with computer problem solving generally but I have zero experience with Access (and the database is important to the company I'm working for so I don't want to touch it!).

### So:

After migrating to a new fileshare computer, an Access database stops working when the old share is unshared.

Message states it can't access:

```
\\[old computer name]\Documents and Settings\[username]\too\many\dirs\very\bad\place to\keep it\IMHO\[company name]
```

**That's an absolute path beginning with a hostname right?**

There could be a single variable or constant to amend (doubt it) or any number of references to the old hostname in there.

Solutions I have in mind:

- Replicate the hostname and paths of the old server on the new one.

At first I thought this was "not very clever" but it increasingly sounds like the most intelligent move I could make, at least in the short term.

- Install a lightweight *nix VM and replicate the hostname and path on that.

This is too clever. It would add uncertainty, I'm not *nix guy either. (although at least I do in fact *want to* be *nix guy whereas I have no intention of making stuff using MS Access).

- It's not impossible to run a Windows VM on the new fileshare computer but it's a bit weak.

I'd be learning useful stuff but it would use a Windows licence.

Comment: Have you tried using **hosts** and **lmhosts** files to "trick" the Access database into going where you want it? This assumes, of course, that identically named file share(s) exist on the new computer.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking for, from your question it seems your are looking for advice worth virtual machine, but your question doesn't have that tag. If you're looking for help with Access, then check what's in the referenced folder (Access probably not referring to folders, there are some files in that used by the db), that hopefully will give you some hint where to look for the reference (can be hard coded in VBA, a variable, value in a table...)

Comment: @BillP3rd I didn't think the hosts file could be that specific ie just for one file at an address. Sounds like it would make too many things work differently

Comment: @Máté Juhász I'm sorry, the way I first posted, it was a bit VM heavy. ....

I can't afford to spend time digging around in Access, the data is too important for the job to be handed to volunteers (we have those!) and staff here don't have these skills....

The question "How to fix an MS Access related prob using anything except MS Access" isn't very Stackoverflow so it's here.

Comment: It's still not clear what are you asking for. You describe a problem and present a potential answer, but no question in your post.